# Which yaml tag for I18n translation of action buttons in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, rails-i18n

In my RoR 5.2 application, I create buttons for specific actions:

```
<%= button_to t('MakeCurrent'), make_current_business_rule_path(@business_rule.id), class: "buttons mid_menu" %>
```

I tried to insert the translated label in a helpers yaml file:

```
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      business_area:
        create: "Create Business Area"
        update: "Update Business Area"
        MakeCurrent: "Activate this version"
```

It works for the create and update labels that are part of a standard form, but not with the MakeCurrent label passed to the button_to method. Which would be the correct entry point in the yaml structure ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats just not how I18n lookup works. The form helpers will automatically use the scoped keys as thats a limited use case. It would be very suprising and quite frankly stupid if Rails just wildly guessed that an arbitrary button is the same thing as submitting a form.

If you want to use that key you can use the full path or pass a scope to `I18n.t`:

```
t('helpers.submit.business_area.MakeCurrent')
t('MakeCurrent', scope: 'helpers.submit.business_area')
```

If you want to make the lookup dynamic based on the model you can use [ActiveModel::Naming](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html#method-i-model_name) to get the translation key:

```
t('MakeCurrent', scope: [:helpers, :submit, @object.class.model_name.i18n_key])
```

You should also name your keys in snake_case to follow the principle of least suprise.